# Mac Mini 2018 Ethernet option 1 vs. 10 GB

Tags: mac-mini, ethernet

What is advantage of 10 GB Ethernet vs. 1 GB Ethernet in the new Mac Mini?

Where is it important or helpful to have the 10 Gbps option that costs $100 extra.

Comment: 10 GB is faster transfer speeds.

Comment: Mac minis are commonly used as servers and servers often require lots of bandwidth (i.e. file transfers), thus the higher bandwidth option.  The general user will, more often than not, have no need for a 10GB connection.  Keep in mind, to achieve 10GB speeds, your infrastructure (switch, other computers/severs, and even your cabling) must support 10GB speeds.

Answer (score 2):

10 GB/s transfer speeds are faster than 1 GB/s transfer speeds.

From the Mac mini purchase page

> Mac mini has some of the most versatile ports and connectivity options
>   of any Mac, allowing it to serve and adapt to a wide variety of
>   situations and workflows. Mac mini comes standard with
>   10/100/1000BASE-T Gigabit (1Gb) Ethernet using an RJ-45 connector. For
>   network connections that are up to 10 times faster, Mac mini has a
>   10Gb Ethernet option. The 10Gb Ethernet option supports Nbase-T
>   industry-standard 1Gb, 2.5Gb, 5Gb, and 10Gb network speeds using an
>   RJ-45 connector. With 10Gb Ethernet, Mac mini will provide higher
>   connectivity bandwidth for sharing files between desktops, working
>   with high-performance network storage, or large-capacity data loads.

Answer (score 2):

Your Mac Mini is flexible.

It comes preset for 1 Gbps (Gigabit per second).

That same plug (RJ-45) can be configured for speeds up to 10 Gbps.

So what does that mean ? You could transfer a 3.6 GB high definition movie from one computer to another in 3 seconds with the 10 Gbps. With 1 Gbps it will take about 10 times longer (30 seconds).

Why ?

For those occasion when your work in a place that has extremely high (10Gbps) computer to computer cable connection (the Ethernet).

However that speed is useless for Internet. At best you can get 1 Gbps Internet speed (with fiber optic providers).

Never than less your Mac Mini is a one mean machine:

Ethernet on mac mini

10/100/1000BASE-T Gigabit Ethernet (RJ-45 connector)
Configurable to 10Gb Ethernet (Nbase-T Ethernet with support for 1Gb, 2.5Gb, 5Gb, and 10Gb Ethernet using RJ-45 connector)

Comment: If you plug in a Mac Mini that has a 10Gbps port into a standard 10/100/1000Base-T port, will the Mac Mini still be able to establish a connection? I'm confused because the Apple documentation states the Mac Mini uses NBase-T.

Comment: Yes, Anil. The mini and the switch can be set to 'auto-negotiate' and end up at the fastest common speed that both ends are capable of.